# Group an item with the same value into one row using the php foreach statement

Tags: php

if I have a php foreach statement that prints a list of values of an items and its corresponding price, Now in simple I want to be able to print just an item from a list of items which have the same values in the list.
            for instance 
            the array of items is like this.

```
        ID  Values  price
        1   Apple    10
        2   Mango    24
        3   Apple    30
        4   Mango    50
```

Now I want to be able to have just two rows from this four rows since they have equal values using the php foreach statement
            This is wat i expect

```
        Values      price
        Apple       40  
        Mango       74
```

This is what I have tried, buh im lack of knowledge in that regard, I would be happy if someone could help

```
            ...
            foreach($v as $kk=>$vv){

                    $values= $vv['Values']; 
                    $price= $vv['Price'];   

                    echo $values.'---'.$price.'<br/>';  

                }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in PHP when you can use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` in SQL? (I'm *assuming* your data comes from the DB)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, I can use SQL to do this buh I wanted to use the foreach to do this because of requirement sake. Is it not possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it'd be like ordering an entire car when all you want is to know what radio channels the car radio can play. Imagine you have 2 million rows - why would you send all of this to PHP when MySQL can do the calculation and just return the few bytes you actually need?

Comment: @h2ooooooo there are more to what I am doing, but just needed to break through from this problem then i can move on to what i am required to do. As i mentioned earlier, its a requirement for what i am doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
//Create your array to store informations
$finalResult = array();

foreach($sqlResult as $key =>$value )
{
     //Ex : if 'Apple' doesnt exist, create it
     if(false === isset($finalResult[$key]))
     {
          $finalResult[$key] = 0;
     }
     //Increment with value
     $finalResult[$key] += (int) $value;
}

var_dump($finalResult);
```